# Only the first attempt to dynamically create a dialog works, and all the following attempts just repeat the same result

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a function which always works fine to dynamically create a page. However, it becomes problematic, if I add

```
`data-rel="dialog"`
```

to the target URL. The symptom is that I can successfully generate the dynamic dialog for the first time, and my following attempts to generate a different dialog cannot work any more and would repeat to display the first-time dialog.
In investigation, I found the

```
`$page.children(":jqmData(role=content)")`
```

returns null starting the second time. Does anyone knows why and how to fix?

Please see the example here, http://jsfiddle.net/RtYuP/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by changing

```
$page.children(":jqmData(role=content)")
```

to

```
$page.find(":jqmData(role=content)")
```

because after a dialog is enhanced, the content container is no more an immediate child of the original div.